# Importing class methods

Tags: lua

The question is rather simple, but I didn't find much on the internet. 
File1: here I have defined a class
File2: here I have defined a class method
Goal: import and call the class method inside file1

At first I tried something like this:

```
-- File2

example = {}

function example.myClass.myMethod()
    -stuff here
end

return example
```

And then

```
-- File1
local example = require "File2"

myobject = myClass:new()
example.myObject.myMethod()
```

I don't think this works, so I'd like to know if there's a way.

Comment: File2 gives a runtime error: attempt to index a nil value (field 'myClass').

Comment: The example you included in your question does not work for a number of minor issues. if i assume you intended to put `myobject = example.myClass.new()`  on line 5 of File1, then you did not define an `example.myClass.new` in File2. And your last line in File1 should be `myObject.myMethod()` as `myObject` is not a member of example. A resource for OOP Lua: http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientationTutorial